# Python - DM a User Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, dm

I'm working on a User Discord Bot in Python .If the bot owner types `!DM @user` then the bot will DM the user that was mentioned by the owner.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!DM'):
        msg = 'This Message is send in DM'
        await client.send_message(message.author, msg)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the `discord.ext.commands` extension.  Here we use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to get the target user, and a [keyword-only argument](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) as an optional message to send them:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def DM(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    message = message or "This Message is sent via DM"
    await bot.send_message(user, message)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

---

For the newer 1.0+ versions of discord.py, you should use `send` instead of `send_message`

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def DM(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    message = message or "This Message is sent via DM"
    await user.send(message)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: No longer useful since the migration to v1.0 as suggested by [@Torxed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62518928/1045783)

Answer (score 3):

Since the big migration to v1.0, `send_message` no longer exists.
Instead, they've [migrated to `.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#migrating-1-0-sending-messages) on each respective endpoint (members, guilds etc).

An example for v1.0 would be:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content == '!verify':
        await message.author.send("Your message goes here")
```

Which would DM the sender of `!verify`. Like wise, you could do:

```
for guild in client.guilds:
    for channel in guild.channels:
        channel.send("Hey yall!")
```

If you wanted to send a "hi yall" message to all your servers and all the channels that the bot is in.

Since it might not have been entirely clear *(judging by a comment)*, the tricky part might get the users identity handle from the client/session. If you need to send a message to a user that **hasn't** sent a message, and there for is outside of the `on_message` event. You will have to either:

1. Loop through your channels and grab the handle based on some criteria
2. Store user handles/entities and access them with a internal identifier

But the only way to send to a user, is through the client identity handle which, in `on_message` resides in `message.author`, or in a channel that's in `guild.channels[index].members[index]`. To better understand this, i recommend reading the official docs on [how to send a DM?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm).

Comment: You're correct about `send`, but this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh in what way doesn't it answer how to send a message to a user? That's exactly what my first code snippet does. You have to find the user handle object and call the `.send()` on that entity. Either by looping a channel or via a `on_message` request.

Comment: ".If the bot owner types `!DM @user` then the bot will DM the user that was mentioned by the owner."

Answer (score 0):

I used this command in the past and it in my opinion it works the best for me:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mall(ctx, *, message):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  for user in ctx.guild.members:
    try:
      await user.send(message)
      print(f"Successfully DMed users!")
    except:
      print(f"Unsuccessfully DMed users, try again later.")
```

Answer (score 0):

````py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    if message == None:
      message = "Hi!"
    embed = make_embed(title=f"Sent by {user}", desc=message)
    await user.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send("Message sent!")```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that each code I put into my code lines they don't work completely, so I added my *own bit* to them and bam it works! When adding this to your bot's code, don't forget to add the bot's name where it says *bot name here*. It will only DM the person who sent it, but you can change what it says each day for a surprise for everyone that used the command. It works every time for me.

```
@client.command()
async def botdm(ctx):
  await ctx.message.author.send('hi my name is *bot name here* and i am a bot!')
```