# Sending a message to a specific user specified in the message, discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In my discord.py code I am trying to set up a simple send  message to a user that the message author has specified.

```
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
  print("Hello DIRECT MESSAGE")
  msg = "Why hello there"
  print (message.author)
  await client.send_message(message.author, msg)

if message.content.startswith('!poke'):
  print("Poke DIRECT MESSAGE")
  a = message.content[6:]
  print(a)
  msg = "Hi there"
  await client.send_message(a, msg)
```

The !hello command works fine, but I do not know how to get the User ID as an object for the send message command after receiving their ID as a string.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343245/python-dm-a-user-discord-bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get).

Assuming this is happening in a server, where both the command invoker and the target are:
`target = discord.utils.get(message.server.members, id=a)`