# Discord.py - How do I send private message to someone using the person's Id?

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to know how do I send private messages to someone with they'r ID

Help

Comment: You have not mentioned anything about where you are stuck at and your work.

Comment: Is the id in your code, or supplied by a user when the bot is running?  For the former, use [`Client.get_user_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) and for the later use a converter [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343245/python-dm-a-user-discord-bot)

Answer (score 9):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx):
    user=await client.get_user_info("User's ID here")
    await client.send_message(user, "Your message goes here")
    # This works ^
```

Comment: Although I answered the question, this is s duplicate to [Python - DM a User Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343245/python-dm-a-user-discord-bot?). It's better to research first next time

Answer (score 1):

```
async def msg(ctx,userid:str,*,msg):
       user = ctx.message.server.get_member(userid) or user = client.get_member(userid)
       await client.send_message(user,msg)
```

Hope this will helps you!.