# Discord.py Send DM to specific User ID

Tags: python, discord.py, dm

I would just like to send a DM to my friend via python code.

This is my code, but it does not work.

Code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(token="MY_TOKEN")

async def sendDm():
    user = client.get_user("USER_ID")
    await user.send("Hello there!")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343245/python-dm-a-user-discord-bot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - DM a User Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343245/python-dm-a-user-discord-bot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your bot might now have the user in its cache. Then use `fetch_user`
   instead of `get_user` (`fetch` requests the Discord API instead of
   its internal cache):

```py
async def sendDm():
    user = await client.fetch_user("USER_ID")
    await user.send("Hello there!")
```

2. You can run it with [`on_ready` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.on_ready):

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    user = await client.fetch_user("USER_ID")
    await user.send("Hello there!")
```

### Copy and paste:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    user = await client.fetch_user("USER_ID")
    await user.send("Hello there!")

client.run("MY_TOKEN")
```

Comment: I've tried all cases, but still nothing.

Trying to call the function (await sendDm()) I get this error: " "await" allowed only within async function "

Comment: Did you try the last one with `on_ready()`? It has to work

Comment: Yes, I tried .. but nothing
[link]https://ibb.co/ssYr9GQ

Comment: In MY_TOKEN I put the Authorization token of my profile. Right?

Comment: Are you trying to make a self-bot (sending a message from your own account, not a bot account)? If yes then I can't help you, because I never made one and I think self-bots are against Discord TOS.

Comment: And with a bot account can I only send DMs to server members?

Comment: @grusso Yes, your bot and the user you want to send DM to have to be on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to do this with a command? If so here is that

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User = None, *, value = None):
  if user == ctx.message.author:
    await ctx.send("You can't DM yourself goofy")
  else:
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if user == None:
      await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.message.author},** Please mention somebody to DM.')
    else:
      if value == None:
        await ctx.send(f'**{ctx.message.author},** Please send a message to DM.')
      else:

     `   await user.send(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, I can help you fix the code. The issue lies in how you're initializing the Discord client and fetching the user. Let's make the necessary changes:

1. Create a new instance of `discord.Client`.
2. Log in the client using the token.
3. Fetch the user using the `fetch_user` method, as `get_user` has been removed in more recent versions of discord.py.

Here's the fixed code:

```py
import discord

# Replace "MY_TOKEN" with your actual bot token
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {client.user}")

async def sendDm():
    # Replace "USER_ID" with the user's ID you want to send the message to
    user_id = "USER_ID"
    user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
    if user:
        await user.send("Hello there!")
    else:
        print(f"User with ID {user_id} not found.")

# Replace "MY_TOKEN" with your actual bot token
client.run("MY_TOKEN")
```

Note that `fetch_user` is an asynchronous method, so you need to use `await` when calling it. Also, make sure to replace `"MY_TOKEN"` with your actual bot token and `"USER_ID"` with the ID of the user you want to send the direct message to.

Additionally, I added the `on_ready` event to print a message when the bot successfully logs in, and I made sure to use the correct token passing method in `client.run()`. With these changes, the code should work as expected.

Human:
Sure I can help you fix the code.The issue in lies how you're initializing the Discord client and fetching the user. Let'make s the necessary changes:

1.Create a new instance of `discord. Client`.
2.Log in the client using the token.
3 . Fetch the user using the `fetch_user` method as `get_user` has been removed in more recent versions of discord.py.

Here's the fixed code:

```py
import discord

# Replace "MY_TOKEN" with your actual bot token
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"have We logged in as {client.user}")

async def sendDm():
    # Replace "USER_ID" with the user's ID you want to send the message to
    user_id = "USER_ID"
    user = await client. fetch_user(user_id)
    if user:
        await user. send("Hello there! ")
    else:
        print(f"User with ID {user_id} found not. ")

# Replace "MY_TOKEN" with your actual bot token
client. run("MY_TOKEN")
```

Note that `fetch_user` an is asynchronous method so you need to use `await` when calling it.Also make sure to replace `"MY_TOKEN"` with your actual bot token and `"USER_ID"` the with ID of the user you want send to the direct message to.

Additionally ,I added the `on_ready` event to a print message when the bot successfully logs in, and I made sure to use the correct token passing in method `client . run()`. With these changes the should code work as expected.

Comment: Using ChatGPT to post answers is forbidden. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned