# How do you send a private message to ctx.author in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

## This is how you would send a message...

In discord.py:

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="your password is 123")
await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

But oh no... That password was (although it was replied to the command user) displayed PUBLICALLY and I do now want that... How would you make the reply private to only the ctx.author?

Why does this not work?

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="yay")
await ctx.reply(ctx.author, embed=embed)
```

Comment: I hope this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343245/python-dm-a-user-discord-bot

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message to `ctx.author` like this:

```py
await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work :D

```
channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Or you could do

```
await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
```

I think both work